# replace all elements with id format when the page loads

Tags: javascript

i want to Replace all id format: Image*
**My html:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<label class="control-label abc-control-label"  id="image3">![](https://i.imgur.com/pMRNwuY.png)</label>
<br>
<label class="control-label abc-control-label"  id="image2">![](https://i.imgur.com/ZE8HMqh.png)</label>
<br>
<label class="control-label abc-control-label" id="image1">![](https://i.imgur.com/P92SWSj.png)</label>
<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZE8HMqh.png" style="width:200px">
```

**My Javascript:**

```
function changeImage () {
    var element = document.getElementById('image2');
    //myelement.innerHTML= "New Text";
    $image_markdown = element.innerHTML;
$image_format = $image_markdown.match(/!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/)[1];
$new_image = '<img src="' + $image_format + '" style="width:200px">'
element.innerHTML = $new_image;
}

window.onload = changeImage();
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/n5fmj03c/26/

My above code work only image2.

And Please help to all image.

I want to change all elements with `id ="image*"` in my above code to new_image.

[image]

Comment: Prefixing variables with `$` is pretty unconventional in JS. You should also try to stick to one case (either `snake_case` or `camelCase`) and naming convention (either prefix `$` or don't). Most importantly: Make sure to **declare your variables**, otherwise they may override properties on the global/`Window` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` with the selector `[id^=image]` to get all elements whose id starts with `"image"`, then loop over them to perform this image replacement.

```js
function changeImage() {
  for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('[id^=image]')) {
    $image_markdown = element.innerHTML;
    $image_format = $image_markdown.match(/!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/)[1];
    $new_image = '<img src="' + $image_format + '" style="width:200px">'
    element.innerHTML = $new_image;
  }
}
changeImage();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label abc-control-label" id="image3">![](https://i.imgur.com/pMRNwuY.png)</label>
<br>
<label class="control-label abc-control-label" id="image2">![](https://i.imgur.com/ZE8HMqh.png)</label>
<br>
<label class="control-label abc-control-label" id="image1">![](https://i.imgur.com/P92SWSj.png)</label>
<br>
```